# Multiple text fields inside of kivy text input

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on on a scientific calculator using kivy, is there a way i insert multiple text fields in kivy text input like in below image.  thanks for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want, but you can combine `TextInput` widgets. Here is an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<-TextInputNoBorder@TextInput>:
    # eliminates the TextInput border
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba:
                (self.cursor_color
                if self.focus and not self._cursor_blink
                else (0, 0, 0, 0))
        Rectangle:
            pos: self._cursor_visual_pos
            size: root.cursor_width, -self._cursor_visual_height
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_foreground_color if self.disabled else (self.hint_text_color if not self.text else self.foreground_color)

<MyTextInput@BoxLayout>:
    # combine three TextInput Widgets to appear as one
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInputNoBorder:
        id: ti1
        text: 'This is One'
    TextInputNoBorder:
        id: ti2
        text: 'This is Two'
    TextInputNoBorder:
        id: ti3
        text: 'This is Three'
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Factory.MyTextInput()

TestApp().run()
```

This example just stacks three `TextInput` widgets vertically, but they could be arranged and sized in many ways. The `TextInputNoBorder` widget extends the `TextInput` widget by redefining its appearance (eliminating the border).

Comment: Thanks you. However i run this code and am getting attributeError: 'TextInputNoBorder' object has no attribute '_cursor_visual_pos'

Comment: That is defined in `TextInput`, and my code does not affect that definition. Something else must be happening in your code.

Comment: I got the code to run, however this doesn't solve my problem. I want a proper maths formatting.

Comment: That has nothing to do with fields in a `TextInput`. That is all about fonts.

Comment: Fonts? But I'm using asana font, or is there any better font for this purpose?